# Print Greek letter in printed string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, unicode, python-unicode

How do i get this to print the eta symbol please?? At the moment it just returns $\eta$ as opposed to the actual letter.

```
print(r'The conversion factor from z to $\eta$ is %a' %round(n,4))
```

Comment: Find the symbol you want from a character table and just copy it. I suspect you don't want the letter Η or η, but some mathematical symbol like  , etc. I just typed the letters, and copied the symbols from the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a [number of eta characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eta#Character_encodings).  You can print them using their names from the unicode standard:

```
import unicodedata as ud

>>> for eta in etas:
...     print(eta, ud.lookup(eta))
... 
GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ETA Η
GREEK SMALL LETTER ETA η
GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ETA Η
GREEK SMALL LETTER ETA η
MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL ETA 
MATHEMATICAL BOLD SMALL ETA 
MATHEMATICAL ITALIC CAPITAL ETA 
MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL ETA 
MATHEMATICAL BOLD ITALIC CAPITAL ETA 
MATHEMATICAL BOLD ITALIC SMALL ETA
```

Or by escaping their names like this: `\N{NAME}`:

```
>>> print('\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ETA}')
Η
```

Or using unicode hex escape sequences, like this:

```
>>> print('GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ETA \u0397')
GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ETA Η

>>> print('GREEK MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL ETA \U0001d6ae')
GREEK MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL ETA
```

Comment: Or simply copy the characters from that page

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos where's the fun in that? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This website provides some helpful suggestions:
https://pythonforundergradengineers.com/unicode-characters-in-python.html

```
>>> print('Omega: \u03A9')
Omega: Ω
>>> print('Delta: \u0394')
Delta: Δ
>>> print('sigma: \u03C3')
sigma: σ
>>> print('mu: \u03BC')
mu: μ
>>> print('epsilon: \u03B5')
epsilon: ε
>>> print('degree: \u00B0')
degree: °
>>> print('6i\u0302 + 4j\u0302-2k\u0302')
6î + 4ĵ-2k̂
```